# Group dataframe by some columns, do nothing, display result

Tags: python, pandas

I  have a Pandas dataframe and need to group its values by some columns, then do nothing, finally show the resulting dataframe. This might appear as a strange operation, but it is only for visualisation purposes as I need to format the dataframe in a Latex tabular environment.

Consider this example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    dict(a=1, b=2, c=3),
    dict(a=1, b=2, c=4),
    dict(a=1, b=2, c=3),
    dict(a=2, b=1, c=5),
    dict(a=2, b=1, c=9)
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
display(df)

print("reindexed")
df2 = df.set_index(["a", "b"]).sort_index()
display(df2)
```

with outputs:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
2  1  2  3
3  2  1  5
4  2  1  9

reindexed
     c
a b   
1 2  3
  2  4
  2  3
2 1  5
  1  9
```

I do not want repeated values in the column `b`. The desired output would be:

```
     c
a b   
1 2  3
     4
     3
2 1  5
     9
```

I am not able to achieve this, even if it should be quite simple. I tried to use group-by:

```
print("grouped")
df3 = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).apply(lambda x: x)
print(df3)
```

but with this result:

```
grouped
       a  b  c
a b           
1 2 0  1  2  3
    1  1  2  4
    2  1  2  3
2 1 3  2  1  5
    4  2  1  9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to force the display of pandas objects.

The last level of a MultiIndex is always visible.

If this is just for a quick display, you could however cheat and add an invisible level:

```
df2 = df.assign(**{'': ''}).set_index(["a", "b", '']).sort_index()
```

Output:

[image]